# Perl change only part of matched regex

Tags: regex, perl

I've got a program that reads in lines and changes parts of them as long as there isn't a back slash immediately in front of it.

For example, if the word foo was going to be changed to bar, the sentance

```
Hello foo, thisfoo likes \foo
```

Would become

```
Hello bar, thisbar likes \foo
```

If the line is stored in $line, my code is

```
$line =~ s/[(^\\)]foo/bar/g;
```

but of course that results in an output of

```
Hellobar, thibar likes \foo
```

Is there a way for the regex search to find some requirement of the string, but not include it in what is altered? Or is there some kind of workaround. The only thing I can think of is replace all of the occurrences of `\foo` with some other string and replace it back again afterwards but that's definitely not ideal because I can't guarantee what will be in the input.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workaround you can use is a lookaround :)

You can use a negative lookbehind:

```
$line =~ s/(?<!\\)foo/bar/g;
```

This will match `foo` unless it has a backslash before it.

Also, I would like to point out that your current regex doesn't work as you might think it works:

```
$line =~ s/[(^\\)]foo/bar/g;
```

`[(^\\)]` should be matching any of `(`, `)`, `^`, or `\`. What you probably meant was `[^\\]`